# Copy of a closure instead of a reference

Tags: javascript, closures, private, accessor

I'm currently writting a javascript script.

```
employe.name = Remi
employe2 = Object.create(Employe);
employe2.name = Vautrin
console.log(employe.name);//Vautrin instead of Remi
```

I was just wondering how to copy a full object. I've already tried :

```
 //StackOverFlow
function clone(obj) {

    if (obj == null || typeof (obj) != 'object')
        return obj;

    var temp = obj.constructor(); // changed

    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

This is the closure code :

```
var Employe = (function(){
    return {
        name = "Hello";
     };        
})();
```

But whenever I call a method, I get an error of non defined function.

Could you help me please ? :D

**Second attempt**

```
var EdT = (function() {
    var _nbJoursTravaille = 0;
    var _semaine ;
    var _proprietaire;
    return {
        constructor: function(proprietaire) {
            _proprietaire = proprietaire;

            return this;
        },
    };
```

});

```
var Employe = (function() {
    var _id;
    var _nom;
    var _prenom;
    var _metier;
    var _tel;
    var _edT ;
    return {
        constructor: function(id, nom, prenom, metier, tel) {
            _id = id;
            _nom = nom;
            _prenom = prenom;
            _metier = metier;
            _tel = tel;
            _edT= Object.create(EdT).constructor(nom + " " + prenom);
            return this;
        },
//.... Some code
     };
});

var employe = Object.create(Employe).constructor("id", "nom", "Rémi", "AlmostJsDev", "+33");
var employe2 =Object.create(Employe).constructor("id", "nom", "Rémi1234", "AlmostJsDev", "+33");
console.log(employe.getEdT().getProprietaire()); //Remi1234
```

**Third Attempt**

```
var EDT = (function(){
     this.proprietaire;
     return {
       constructor : function(proprietaire){
             this.proprietaire = proprietaire;
        }
      };
})();
```

`console.log(employe.getEdT()._proprietaire);`

It should be private ; instead it's public (seems legit) ... How to fix that ?

Comment: Object.create doesn't deep clone, how prototype and constructor functions work is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711  as for cloning objects; that is a complicated issue. Sometimes you want to deep clone members and sometimes you want to leave them as references to other objects.

Comment: Hello, could you show me some code for a constructor ? I do not understand how to make one in my case. Would it be : 
var Employe = (function(){
    return {
     construct(name){
        this.name = name || "default";
    }   
     name = "Hello";
     };        
})();

Comment: The link in the comment shows several. A constructor is just a function but invoked with the new keyword.

Comment: So I have a new problem : How to make the attributes "private"?

Comment: I never do but there is a link to a protected pattern, that should cover how to simulate private members as well.

Comment: In fact, the link explain what I've done ... sorry... could somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
employe2.name = Vautrin
```

it will see if employe2 has a "name" property on itself. Since it could not find one, it creates a "name" property on the employe2 object, and hence the output of your code is "Remi" only.

The way `Object.create(a,b)` works is create a empty function, set it's prototype value to **a**, then create a new object using this function. Add the properties mentioned in **b** to the newly created object.

So when you wrote Object.create(employe);

It created a new object and set it's prototype to employe.

Read about how property lookups are handled for prototypes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work/26830003#26830003).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think I'm not getting it. Why has the employe2 no name property? How could I fix that? And Why should you think the output is "Remi"?

Comment: Okay, so I get it ! The employe2 is a reference to employe which is a reference to Employe, which has a reference of employe, isn't it ?
How could I clone the object with Object.create without having to redefine every single parameters?

Comment: @user3922129: employe2 has a 'reference' to employe. When you do property lookup from employe2 in a read mode, it shows "Remi". If on the other hand, the property lookup is done in a write mode it creates a new property(if not already present) on the object(that we are working on).

Comment: @user3922129: I am sorry, but I am not able to understand your requirement.